# Ruby showel operator vs (?:) conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code:

```
@ids = []
x = 'a'
@ids << x == 'a' ? [1,2] : [3,4]
@ids
```

I expect that in next line the @ids value should be 
`@ids = [1,2]`, but I obtain `@ids = ['a']`

Why ?

Comment: `@ids << (x == 'a' ? [1, 2] : [3, 4])` will work. Without () the << will just take in the value of x.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Operations are executed in the order of their precedence.
The operations in your relevant line of code are executed in that order:

1. <<
2. ==
3. ?, :

See the full list at [Ruby's operation precedence.](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html)

Here, parenthesis indicate what actually happens in your example:

```
(((@ids << x) == 'a') ? [1,2] : [3,4])
^^^----1----^       ^                ^
||---------2--------|                |
|------------------3-----------------|
```

To get the result you expected, write

```
@ids << (x == 'a' ? [1,2] : [3,4])
```

or

```
@ids.push(x == 'a' ? [1,2] : [3,4])
```

I hope you find this helpful.